# compare two following values in numpy array

Tags: python, indexing, loops, numpy, iteration

What is the best way to touch two following values in an numpy array?

example:

```
npdata = np.array([13,15,20,25])
for i in range( len(npdata) ):
    print npdata[i] - npdata[i+1]
```

this looks really messed up and additionally needs exception code for the last iteration of the loop. 
any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

numpy provides a function `diff` for this basic use case

```
>>> import numpy
>>> x = numpy.array([1, 2, 4, 7, 0])
>>> numpy.diff(x)
array([ 1,  2,  3, -7])
```

Your snippet computes something closer to `-numpy.diff(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

How about `range(len(npdata) - 1)` ?

Here's code (using a simple array, but it doesn't matter):

```
>>> ar = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> for i in range(len(ar) - 1):
...   print ar[i] + ar[i + 1]
... 
3
5
7
9
```

As you can see it successfully prints the sums of all consecutive pairs in the array, without any exceptions for the last iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ediff1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ediff1d.html#numpy.ediff1d) to get differences of consecutive elements. More generally, `a[1:] - a[:-1]` will give the differences of consecutive elements and can be used with other operators as well.